# Clustered index ordered by DESC in Entity Framework Core 6 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a Microsoft SQL Server table called `Log` where I store a big number of log entries. The typical query is to fetch log rows for the last few days, weeks or months.

So what I learned is that a clustered index on the timestamp of when the log entry was written would be a clever solution for querying the table. Simply speaking, with a clustered index on the timestamp, the table itself is somewhat ordered on that column and the query goes fast.

But I cannot understand how I can create the clustered index with a descending order with Entity Framework Core code-first.

This is my current code that seems to create the index correctly but it is with ASC ordering.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LogEntryEntity>()
            .HasKey(c => c.LogEntryId)
            .IsClustered(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<LogEntryEntity>()
            .HasIndex(c => c.LogTimestamp)
            .HasDatabaseName("LogEntryClusteredIndex")
            .IsClustered(true);
```

Now, I saw one some SO posts that this is a known issue and not trivial to solve as far as I understood. But I am wondering if that is outdated information and/or if somebody has any tips of how to change the ordering to DESC. And if the above code is correct?

I am using Entity Framework Core 6.0.0-preview.7

Answer (score 1):

EF6 does not support index sort options :(. The index sort feature is being introduced in EF Core 7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

you can use an IsDescending() index builder

```
//
// Summary:
//     Configures the sort order(s) for the columns of this index (ascending or descending).
//
//
// Parameters:
//   descending:
//     A set of values indicating whether each corresponding index column has descending
//     sort order. An empty list indicates that all index columns will have descending
//     sort order.
//
// Returns:
//     The same builder instance so that multiple configuration calls can be chained.
public new virtual IndexBuilder<T> IsDescending(params bool[] descending)
{
    return (IndexBuilder<T>)base.IsDescending(descending);
}
```

or data anatations:

```
[Index(nameof(Url), nameof(Rating), IsDescending = new[] { false, true })]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

for example

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasIndex(b => new { b.FirstName, b.LastName })
    .HasDatabaseName("IX_Names_Descending")
    .IsDescending(true, false);
```

will create an index with FirstName DESC and LastName ASC sorting.

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot understand how I can create the clustered index DESC with Entity Framework Core code first.

You can use a [Custom Migration Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations)

But why do you want to switch the index order?  It shouldn't be any faster to insert or query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought it would be a lot faster if the table is sorted DESC. For instance if I want to fetch the rows that where inserted the last 24 hours. These rows are located in the beginning of the table when its DESC but at the end of the table when its ASC.